# how to get the input value and then check that against all of an arrays object values at the 0 index

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, input, match

Title says it all.

I have an array of objects shown in the code below. Each object has two values, a type and a weakness. I want a user to be able to put a type into the input field, and then when submitted, check that input value against all of the objects 0 index values. Upon match, I want to return the matching objects 1 index value. I guess I am just too new and missing the easy setup. Can anyone help?
I am new to programming (4 months, self taught), and trying to figure this out, so be gentle. :)

```
const form = document.querySelector("#main");

const button = document.querySelector("#submit");

const types = [
{
    type: "normal",
    weakness: "fighting",
}
];



let results = [];


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let result = document.getElementById("type-input").value.toLowerCase();


    function checkType() {
        if (result.match(types.indexOf[0])) {
            console.log('Yay!');
        };
    };

    checkType();

    form.reset();
});
```

Comment: Can you post an example input and output? I'm confused with all these "indexes".

Comment: Sure! I edited the code to only include one object in the array. So in this case, a user would input "normal' (which would match the 'type' value in the object) into the input field, and the return would show 'fighting' (the weakness variable in the object).

Comment: Get rid of your `checkType` function, and put `if(result === types[0].type){ console.log('Hardly a reason to celebrate.'); }` in its place.

Comment: Thanks @StackSlave! I appreciate the alternative route! I will try this as well. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find` to check if the object with the input in in the object or not

```js
const types = [ { type: "normal", weakness: "fighting", }, { type: "fighting", weakness: "flying, psychic, fairy", }, { type: "flying", weakness: "rock, electric, ice", }, { type: "poison", weakness: "ground, psychic", }, { type: "ground", weakness: "water, grass, ice", }, { type: "rock", weakness: "fighting, ground, steel, water, grass", }, { type: "bug", weakness: "flying, rock, fire", }, { type: "ghost", weakness: "ghost, dark", }, { type: "steel", weakness: "fighting, ground, fire", }, { type: "fire", weakness: "ground, rock, water", }, { type: "water", weakness: "grass, electric", }, { type: "grass", weakness: "flying, poison, bug, fire, ice", }, { type: "electric", weakness: "ground", }, { type: "psychic", weakness: "bug, ghost, dark", }, { type: "ice", weakness: "fighting, rock, steel, fire", }, { type: "dragon", weakness: "ice, dragon, fairy", }, { type: "dark", weakness: "fighting, bug, fairy", }, { type: "fairy", weakness: "poison, ghost, dragon", }, ];

input = "dark";

findType = (input) => {
  let obj = types.find((o) => o.type == input);
  return obj ? obj.weakness : console.log("Object Not FOUND");
};

console.log(findType(input));
```

Comment: Super grateful for the help! I appreciate it! This worked perfectly.

Comment: Happy i could help, also if you have any question regarding the code feel free to ask me

Comment: Of course! New to the site, but I will upvote and mark it now!

Comment: It lets me accept it, and I upvoted, but it wont show publicly yet due to my new account, apparently. 

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: You welcome, if you have any question feel free to ask Happy coding  :)

Comment: Had a quick question... I am currently trying to get an image file to display instead of the text string we worked on. I want to display the image for the type instead of just showing "fire, water, and grass". Any thoughts? I have tried a couple things, but I am failing. I hope all has been well!

Answer (score 1):

my way..

```js
const types = 
      [ { type: 'normal',   weakness: 'fighting'                              } 
      , { type: 'fighting', weakness: 'flying, psychic, fairy'                } 
      , { type: 'flying',   weakness: 'rock, electric, ice'                   } 
      , { type: 'poison',   weakness: 'ground, psychic'                       } 
      , { type: 'ground',   weakness: 'water, grass, ice'                     } 
      , { type: 'rock',     weakness: 'fighting, ground, steel, water, grass' } 
      , { type: 'bug',      weakness: 'flying, rock, fire'                    } 
      , { type: 'ghost',    weakness: 'ghost, dark'                           } 
      , { type: 'steel',    weakness: 'fighting, ground, fire'                } 
      , { type: 'fire',     weakness: 'ground, rock, water'                   } 
      , { type: 'water',    weakness: 'grass, electric'                       } 
      , { type: 'grass',    weakness: 'flying, poison, bug, fire, ice'        } 
      , { type: 'electric', weakness: 'ground'                                } 
      , { type: 'psychic',  weakness: 'bug, ghost, dark'                      } 
      , { type: 'ice',      weakness: 'fighting, rock, steel, fire'           } 
      , { type: 'dragon',   weakness: 'ice, dragon, fairy'                    } 
      , { type: 'dark',     weakness: 'fighting, bug, fairy'                  } 
      , { type: 'fairy',    weakness: 'poison, ghost, dragon'                 } 
      ] 

const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  let result = myForm['type-input'].value.trim().toLowerCase()
    , rowfind = types.find(x=>x.type===result)
    ;
  if(rowfind) console.log(rowfind.weakness )

  myForm.reset()
  }
```

```html
<form action="xxx" id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="type-input" >
  <button type="submit"> submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: @CharlesCline have look on my code to see how to access form elements by their names